# Get the Google contacts page by page c#

Tags: c#, pagination, google-contacts-api

I have developed the app to read the google contacts. I can able to read the contacts, but I'm not sure how to do that page by page. Here, I have attached my sample code.

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(gCredJson)
                    .CreateScoped(Scopes)
                    .CreateWithUser(usrName);

string token = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

To get the contacts

```
OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
parameters.AccessToken = token;

RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("mailApp", parameters);
settings.AutoPaging = true;
settings.Maximum = 2;
settings.PageSize = 2;
ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts("myemail@gmail.com");
foreach (Contact c in f.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name.FullName);
}
```

The above code give me the contacts. But, I don't know how to process the next page. It would be much appreciated anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered to use [ContactsQuery](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Google.GData.Contacts/ContactsQuery/-/php-contactsquery-class-examples.html)? Please check Example #2.

```
var contactsPerQuery = 50;
var maxTotal = 32000;
ContactsQuery query = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
query.NumberToRetrieve = contactsPerQuery;

for (int index = 0; index < maxTotal; index += contactsPerQuery)
{
     query.StartIndex = index;
     Feed<Contact> feed = cr.Get<Contact>(query);
     
     //display contacts from feed.Entries
     ....
}
```

Comment: Please provide an answer that is directly helpful to the OP directly here (e.g. copy and paste (and adapt) code here). Then, you can also add a reference to another website. This helps other people who have the same problem, to arrive here and see the solution.